# Cannot move files from one drive to another in Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 (they copy instead)

Tags: macos

When I try to move a file to my WD My Passport Ultra external drive it just copies the file. It doesn't actually move them. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can you update your question with how you're moving the file?

Comment: Please fix your headline: "I am running on Mac os x El capitain version 10.11.3" is no question!

Comment: If you're dragging and dropping via Finder from one volume to another,  then press and hold the command key while doing so and this will move the file instead of copying it. In the future, please include all relevant details in your question and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 3):

To move a file to a different drive from the one it is on drag the file to the new location while holding down the `Command` key. The green '+' sign on the cursor should not be displayed.

To create an alias hold down `Command`-`Option` while dragging the file. A curved arrow icon will be added to the cursor to indicate an alias will be made.

Comment: There is nothing in the OP about creating an alias and since Reynaldo is apparently trying to move a file it make even less sense to include instruction on how to make an alias.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Most people just copy the files to the other drive and then remove them from the original drive. **However, you can also use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (or Edit Menu > Copy) to copy the file(s) and then paste them to your other drive using the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> shortcut instead of the usual paste shortcut.**

**Long answer**

Since you provided no detail on how you're trying to move the file, this answer assumes you're doing this via the standard Mac OS X El Capitan GUI.

The reason the file is being copied rather than moved is that you're *moving* it from one drive to **another drive**. Doing this implicitly means you're wanting to *copy* it rather than move it (this is how many people transfer documents and manually backup files).

If the files were *moved* by default, rather than copied, this would create a messy situation to try and keep track of. This also isn't what most people would expect, so the user experience would be shocking.

**Imagine this:** You spend a day working on a PowerPoint presentation and then want to put it onto a USB stick to take to a meeting. Would you expect the file to be moved or copied? If it's moved and you lose the USB stick, then what?

Comment: And this is the same behavior in Windows - but here you have the CTRL+X and then CTRL+V to cut and past the file(s).